# Proper route pattern for RESTful collections with additional resources

Tags: rest, collections, routes, hateoas

I have been doing RESTful APIs for quite a bit (exposing and consuming 3rd parties) and I see two following patterns popping up here and there. Each has pros and cons and neither is "clean" in my opinion.

So the situation is: you have a collection resource (e.g. "assets") and you want to expose some additional resources within a collection (e.g. subresources of the collection itself, not the asset, like aggregated view endpoint or some commands).

Two patterns I see are:

1. People create a RESTful collection resource like `/assets/${asset-id}` and expose everything else they need like `GET /assets/owned`, `GET /assets/summary`, `POST /assets/recheck-inventory`. This looks neat and concise but introduces a clash between `${asset-id}` and nouns of sub-resource URLs (e.g. `asset12345` and `summary` are in the same place in the URL).
2. Others do `/assets/items/${asset-id}` and expose everything like `GET /assets/owned`, `GET /assets/summary` and so on. This is cleaner from routing perspective and a bit more future-proof, but adds an extra noun in the route, which leads to confusion when people are trying to do `POST /assets` for example.

The "best practice" guidelines I went through thus far avoid the question altogether. I also understand that REST is a convention and not the standard, and there is a universal "it depends" answer. Still, I feel like there got to be a generic recommendation here.

Hence the question is: which of two you would use?

UPDATE: to clarify, let us assume that:

- `/assets/owned` contains entities of different types, not assets, so it is not a query and you can GET/POST/DELETE items in it.
- `/assets/summary` is an aggregation document (e.g. report with quantities for example)
- `/assets/recheck-inventory` is a command (i.e. POST only)

Also, we want to stick with REST principles:

- route's path shall identify an entity and its state uniquely.
- query parameters alter which elements are returned, but do not change the payload format.
- headers are for protocol-level information and do not change service logic (i.e. presentation, security, caching, etc.)

Comment: Regarding one of your last points: The path within a URL can be anything, including just a GUID without hierarchy, and the interface could still be RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like these approaches either, but be aware, that REST does not put constraint on how to design URI structure, so you can do whatever you feel right. Apparently the developers of these webservices felt this approach right.

I would do something like the following with your URIs, since I like flat URIs much better.

```
/assets/items/${asset-id}
  -> /assets/${asset-id}
/assets/owned
  -> /assets/?owned
  -> /assets/?owned=true
/assets/summary
  -> /assets-summary
  -> /assets/ + "Prefer: return=minimal"
```

You can find more about the [prefer header here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240), but be aware, that you need to register it by the [vary header](https://www.fastly.com/blog/best-practices-for-using-the-vary-header) if you want it to be a secondary cache key.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. To be honest I never came across with Prefer/Vary usage thus far. But have seen a few X-WHATEVER-GIVE-ME-WHAT-I-WANT custom headers ;-)

Comment: Overall I agree that flat structure is simpler and often times better. I am trying to figure out how to deal with **nested** resource patterns, other than avoiding them altogether ;-) That's the only reason why I am not marking this as an answer.

Comment: @Borv It is not that hard, it is a simple map reduce. So for example `/assets/` is the whole list and `/assets/x/` is the reduced list with fewer items. The `x` is a filter, which can be `owned`, `$id`, etc... I would put the `summary` into the query and not into the path part `/assets/?summary=1`, since it does not reduce the original collection, it only returns a different representation of the whole `/assets/` collection. If the `$id` can be `"owned"` as well, then you need a prefix before the `$id`, for example: `/assets/id:$id/` or `/assets/id/$id/`, or you can use `owned` as a wildcard.

Comment: this is an interesting suggestion, I never thought of map-reduce semantics for REST. Usually people think opposite (path represents structure, query represents selection or filtering). Do you happen to know any articles or samples? Also good point on identifier. Indeed, putting the brackets around them like in odata (<code>/assets/(12345)</code>) helps to avoid collisions.

Comment: @Borv As far as I remember the URI and IRI standards describe the path as the hierarchical part and the query as the non-hierarchical part of the identifier and you model map reduce as a hierarchy of the main group and the reduced sub-groups. I don't know whether there is an article about this, it is evident to me, so I am pretty sure there is. Google is your friend...